# How to display indoor map using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, openstreetmap, tilecache

I created my osm file in JOSM, and i imported it to my database by osm2pgsql tool.
I created new layer in my osm.xml file, which selecting data with query:

```
select way from planet_osm_line,
(select parts from planet_osm_rels WHERE (((hstore(tags)->'level'))  = '0')) p
where osm_id = any (p.parts))
```

when i run my python script to generate png file i got an error:

> RuntimeError: Postgis Plugin: PostGIS: unable to query the layer
>   extent of table 'planet_osm_rels' because we cannot determine the
>   geometry field name. Please provide either an 'extent' parameter to
>   skip this query, a 'geometry_field' and/or 'geometry_table' parameter,
>   or add a record to the 'geometry_columns' for your table.

is any one can tell me what i'm doing wrong and how i can fix that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I suspect it's to do with the `->` operation (which I don't know about) because I get this error when using "SUBSTRING" in my query.

Comment: i still didn't solve that, operation -> is in some extension to postgres (don't remember the name of it), hstore() change list to hashmap and operator -> returns value from hashmap with given key